# Jenkins pun pipeline via API and pass a file as a parameter

Tags: api, file, jenkins, parameters, size

I want to run the pipeline via the REST API from the script.
This pipeline contains `stashedFile` parameter.
If I use Jenkins UI, I just attach the file from my PC.
But I want to use the REST API for pipeline triggering.
How can I do this?

Note: I did try to change the type of parameter from `stashedFile` to `base64File` but it decreased the maximum file size limit to under 100 KB, which is not acceptable. I want to be able to upload at least 3- to 5-MB files.

I expect to be able to run the pipeline via the Rest API and provide a file content (3- to 5-MB) as a pipeline parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do it simply using Jenkins docs))
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

I used a command like
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/test/job/main/buildWithParameters   --user admin:1124725a00e8af8868651a515fe172c35a   --form HTML=@/home/{myname}/Downloads/index.html